# Getting unexpected result while apllying Join SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fetching data from 4 different tables:

1. leads
2. payu_transactions
3. corporate_user_rides
4. corporate_users

And there are some conditions:

1. user rides should be grater than 0
2. There should be some number of registered and active users
3. There will be some time period

I have written some SQL queries but i am not getting expected result-
The problem is with number of rides count and user count.

For e.g-

Lets say corporate x actually having 38 rides and 23 users but it's showing 7866 rides and 7866 users.

Another corporate y is actually having 18 rides and 5 users but it's showing 90 rides and 90 users.

Can anyone please help, i am not sure what's i am doing here.

I tried this-

**query**

```
SELECT l.id             AS leadId,
       l.corporate_id   AS CorporateID,
       "P-1"            AS priority,
       l.source,
       l.user_name      AS FirstName,
       l.user_name      AS LastName,
       l.corporate_name AS corpName,
       l.user_mail_id   AS email,
       l.phone_number   AS phone,
       l.created_At     AS leadCreation,
       l.comments,
       Count(CU.id)     AS users,
       Count(CUR.id)    AS rides,
       PUT.amount       AS payment
FROM   leads l
       LEFT JOIN payu_transactions PUT
              ON l.user_mail_id = PUT.email
       LEFT JOIN corporate_user_rides CUR
              ON l.corporate_id = CUR.corporate_id
       LEFT JOIN corporate_users CU
              ON l.corporate_id = CU.corporate_id
WHERE  l.created_at BETWEEN '2015-03-16 12:00:00' AND '2016-03-17 12:00:00'
GROUP  BY l.user_mail_id
HAVING Count(CUR.id) > 0
       AND Count(CU.id) > 0
       AND Count(CASE
                   WHEN CU.status IN ( 'active' ) THEN 1
                 END) > 0;
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: On `corporate_user_rides` and `corporate_users` don't you have a field referencing to specific lead id (user)?

Comment: That's corporate_id.

leads has email and corporate_id, so i am joining payu_transactions with email and users and rides with corporate_id.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Count (Distinct column.name)` instead of `Count(column.name)`.

Comment: That's the point of 'distinct'.  You're getting rows in the result with duplicate copies of the distinct IDs.